# Google Play Games Achievements onClose callback

Tags: java, android, callback, google-play-services, google-play-games

Currently we open Achievements View with

> startActivityForResult(mHelper.getGamesClient().getAchievementsIntent(),
>   REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);

Can we get some kind of callback when achievements view was closed? Or if it is possible - to get a callback when user Exits GPG within the achievements view. GameHelper's "onDisconnected()" is not firing for some reason - when that happens.
I've googled this - but found nothing

Edit: should i look for some specific responseCode inside onActivityResult
?

Comment: gamesclient is deprecated. Use this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#getAchievementsIntent(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

Comment: @Clay I dont have a lot of experience with android, how can i get a callback from the thing you linked?

Comment: A callback for what, what do you want to know exactly

Comment: @Clay as i've mentioned in a question - callback for closing Achievements window, or signing out from GPG which can be done from this Achievements popup.

Comment: Ok well when you use startActivityForResult, your activity calls onPause() and then the achievements activity starts. When the user exits out of the achievements activity, your original activity that you called it from will call onResume(). I think that can be used as a "callback". As far as I know there is no in built callback in the google play apis

Comment: Actually, im sorry. You use **startActivityForResult**, therefore, when the user closes the achievements activity, the activity that you called it from gets a call to **onActivityResult** that is your callback

Comment: @Clay but is it possible to know if it closed with player also exiting GPG within this Achievements window? I'm just not shure if instantly checking for isSignedIn will work

Comment: What does GPG stand for?

Comment: @Clay Google Play Games, i meant Google Play Game Services - so GPGS

Comment: Exiting google play games. Do you mean logging out of the users account within the achievements activity?

Comment: The user can only log out of GPGS if you provide a logout button, there is no logout button in the achievements activity so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Clay currently i have only a localized version russian, but there is a button named something like "Settings" and there you can tap "Logout" or "Exit", i dont know exactly its label in english, but when you press it - it will log you out from GPGS. So you can just open settings when Achievements screen is opened and logout there.

Comment: Would you be able to post some screenshots?

Comment: @Clay 
There is a button in a right top corner -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bo7adpvy09f3bm/Achievements_Android.png
By pressing it - you will get a drop down menu with "Settings" or something like that. And there you will be able to "logout" from GPGS

Comment: I see, well, if the user logouts from the achievements screen, you will get a call to `onActivityResult` where the `resultCode` is `GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare this variable and this method in your class.

```
private static int achievementsIntent = 10001;


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == achievementsIntent) {
     //you are in your callback
     if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
         // user logged out from achievements screen
     } 
  }
}
```

Then call your achievements intent:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(GoogleApiClient), achievementsIntent);
```